# Get date from database and control if a month has passed

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I created a form where a user can change his name, saved in a database. I'd like to control, after submit, if the user has already changed his name less than a month ago.

In my database i have a column called "name_changed", where the default data is 0000-00-00 and when the name is changed, the date is saved in "name_changed". But i don't know how controll the month.

Here the HTML code:

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
   <input type="text" class="..." name="name" required>
   <input class="..." type="submit" name="change-name">
</form>
```

Here the PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['change-name']) && $_POST['name'] != ""){ // take data form
                $errors = "0";
                    if(strlen($_POST['name']) < 21){ // control length
                        $name = "$_POST[name]";
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_db WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'";
                        $date_today = date('Y-m-d'); // i don't know if it's right
                        $data_today_month = // take only month
    
                        $date_db = $fetch_info['name_changed']; // take date on db from column "name_changed"
                        $date_db_month = // take only month
                        $diff_between_date_today_month_and_data_db_month = $date_today_month - $date_db_month;
                        if($data_db == '0000-00-00' or $diff_between_date_m_and_data_db_m>= '1'){
                            $update_pass = "UPDATE user SET name = '$name' WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'";
                            $run_query = mysqli_query($con, $update_pass);
                            if($run_query){
                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'";
                                $update_pass = "UPDATE user SET name_changed = '$date' WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'";
                                $run_query = mysqli_query($con, $update_pass);
                            }
                        }else{
                            $count_error = '1';
                            $errors = "you can only change your name once a month!";
                        }
                        
                        
                        }else{
                            $count_error = '1';
                            $errors['db-error'] = "Something wrong!";
                        }
}
```

Thankss

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this for your application SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),name_changed); for the number of days difference. If less than 30, stop the effort. Keep it simple.

Comment: How can i do it with PHP?

Comment: @AlbertoGinco  This URL may help you in PHP.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php  then scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the php date formatting: https://www.adminschoice.com/php-date-format

As you have the line

```
date('Y-m-d')
```

You can also have

```
date("m") --> for only the month.
```

But by doing the check on month, you could potentially have a diff of one month when the user changed his name on 31-jan and also on 1-feb: month 1 and month 2.